# I have been mixing up with the concept of column space, can someone help me with this example as a guide to help me further understand the concept?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the column space of A the same as the column space of the row echelon of A? 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In your example every vector in the column space of $R$ has a $0$ in the last place. This is not true of $A$.

To get a basis for the column space do Gaussian elimination on the *columns.*

Comment: Or refer back to the columns of the original matrix that correspond to pivots in the reduced form.